# Error import data to mongo atlas cluster mongimport

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongoimport

I' trying since 2 days to import data to my mongo cluster using the mongimport command but i'm getting an error

my mongoimport command

```
mongoimport --uri mongodb+srv://cabinetdermes:<MYPASSWORDHERE>@cluster2.ufzkq.mongodb.net/cabinetdermes --collection myData --type json --file /Users/zakisb/Desktop/inventory.crud.json
```

The error that i keep getting

```
2021-10-08T13:33:35.808+0100    error parsing command line options: error parsing uri: lookup cluster2.ufzkq.mongodb.net on 172.20.10.1:53: cannot unmarshal DNS message
```

it's strange because i've already done the import before with another db and it worked successfully. yet this time i' getting error. Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply go to settings and changing my dns adresse.

Answer (score 0):

Use with option --gzip

check [this](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/cannot-unmarshal-dns-message-error-while-importing-data-to-mongo-from-mflix-js/53626/3)

Comment: but my file isn't zipped , or it doesn't have to to use it ?

Comment: also in the forum they're using mongorestore command, i' importing my data locally to a cluster !

Comment: maybe your `DNS` is broken, have you check whether your `DNS` is alive or not

Comment: yes it's working !